# wp_delete_attachment with force and wp_delete_file not working

Tags: wordpress

I've read other questions but they don't apply here... I'm using the basic folder, not a sub-directory or special directory... why is the default behavior not working... I don't want my server piled up with files that don't belong.

```
public static function delete_image_overlay() {
    // Verify nonce for security.
    // check_admin_referer('delete_overlay_image');

    // Make sure we have a post ID.
    if (isset($_POST['feature_route_id']) && is_numeric($_POST['feature_route_id'])) {
        $postId = intval($_POST['feature_route_id']);

        // Check the user has permission to edit the post.
        if (!current_user_can('delete_post', $postId)) {
            wp_die('You do not have permission to delete this post.');
        }
    } else {
        wp_die('Invalid post ID.');
    }

    // Check that the overlay count has been set and is numeric.
    if (isset($_POST['overlay_count']) && is_numeric($_POST['overlay_count'])) {
        $overlayCount = intval($_POST['overlay_count']);
    } else {
        $overlayCount = 0;  // default value
    }

    // Delte meta
    delete_post_meta($postId, 'marker_lat_' . $overlayCount);
    delete_post_meta($postId, 'marker_lng_' . $overlayCount);
    delete_post_meta($postId, 'bounds_sw_lat_' . $overlayCount);
    delete_post_meta($postId, 'bounds_sw_lng_' . $overlayCount);
    delete_post_meta($postId, 'bounds_ne_lat_' . $overlayCount);
    delete_post_meta($postId, 'bounds_ne_lng_' . $overlayCount);

    // Get the attachment ID. This assumes you stored the ID as post meta.
    $attachment_id = get_post_meta($postId, 'attachment_id_' . $overlayCount, true);
    delete_post_meta($postId, 'attachment_id_' . $overlayCount);
    $file_path = get_attached_file($attachment_id);
    // Delete the file
    wp_delete_file($file_path);
    // Delete the attachment.
    wp_delete_attachment($attachment_id, true); // Not deleting the file like its supposed to
    echo json_encode('Deleted - ' . $attachment_id);
    // All done.
    wp_die();
}
```

Comment: `wp_delete_attachment` runs this function [`wp_delete_attachment_files`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_delete_attachment/) so you shouldn't need to use `wp_delete_file($file_path);`.

Comment: Dude, they don't work... I'm so fed up with it... It's killing me!  I'm about to code a workaround